# Background color change on hover not working (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

I'm hoping someone can help me with an issue I am having. I am trying to change the background color of my page when mousing over a nav link on the page. I have tried to use jquery for this (last lines of my js code) but it doesn't seem to be working. I think some of my other Js is interfering in some way because it worked on a simple test page before.
https://codepen.io/adamkelly153/pen/gOGaJYq

```js
$('#hover-01').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#hover-change').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
$('#hover-01').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('#hover-change').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hover-01">Hover this!</div>
<div id="hover-change">Background changes</div>
```

Any help much appreciated! Sorry if I have missed some key info, happy to provide it.
Adam

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is ..?

Comment: For some reason, the span with id `hover-01` is not found (returns null).

Comment: In the pen code you've removed the id: `item.children[0].innerHTML = \`<span style="--index: ${idx};">${letter}</span>\``. Please add the relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: @Teemu Are you able to open the codepen? The background remains black on hover there. Sorry I'm not so experienced at debugging yet and can't find what is specifically causing the problem.

Comment: In my previous comment I've already pointed out why `#hover-01` is not found. SO questions must stand on their own, all the relevant information needed to resolve a problem should be included in the question.

Comment: I understand now @Teemu, thanks for your help and I'll update the question appropriately. Newbie here, still learning - thanks for explaining!

Found a solution now below from the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change `#hover-01` to `.proj-cat` and worked!

```
$('.proj-cat').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('#hover-change').css('background-color', 'blue');
 });
$('.proj-cat').on('mouseleave', function(){
 $('#hover-change').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

https://codepen.io/kian-kpt/pen/zYEvQjW

Comment: For anyone else going "where did `.proj-cat` come from?" It's from the codepen linked at the bottom of the OP. `#hover-01` should have been `#hover-change`, which is it's actual `id`, but you could also just use `body`, which would be a valid selector for that element as well.

Answer (score -1):

Always keep your cdn above your jquery because jquery only works when cdn has been loaded..

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">

$('#hover-01').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('#hover-change').css('background-color', 'blue');
});
$('#hover-01').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('#hover-change').css('background-color', 'red');
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="hover-01">Hover this!</div>
<div id="hover-change">Background changes</div>
```

Comment: Yes, jQuery should be loaded before your code, but `<script>`s should go at the end of the `<body>` because otherwise javascript will try to access document elements that don't exist yet, which will throw errors.